# Is there a term for Saving Abel's style of rock music?

Tags: identify-this-genre

I was wondering if there is a specific term for rhythmic rock music like [*Stupid Girl*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZQaxehjvtI) or [*The Sex is good*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5LLxW0E_eE) by Saving Abel.

The rhythm is not really complex, but very appealing (for me). Yet I have trouble to find similar songs from other artists mainly, because it is hard for me to describe it. It has what I would describe as "groove", though I doubt that is the correct expression.

Any suggestions welcome, it does not need to be accurate as in terms of music theory (that is why I did not ask on [Music: Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/)). I would equally appreciate hints to other bands/artists with this style of music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving Abel are usually described as a **riff-heavy [post-grunge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-grunge) band with [Southern rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_rock) influences**. For a good description of these and related genres, as well as a list of similar Artists, check out [AllMusic](http://www.allmusic.com/artist/saving-abel-mn0000567769) or any online music recommendation system.